# What is the best way to process a vast number of strings keeping unique ones only?

Tags: sqlite, unique, hashset

My program produces a very large number (billions) of fixed-size strings (about 110 characters long) from which I want to extract the unique ones, expecting there to be about 100-200 million.

I cannot fit the entire collection of unique strings into memory, so it has to be a disk-based solution.

As each string is constructed, I need to very quickly decide if it is already in the list or not, and then add it to list if required.

Currently I am using an SQLite database with a single TEXT UNIQUE column and then as each new string is constructed, I call

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ... VALUES('blahblah');
```

which tries to insert the string into the database. If the insertion would violate the UNIQUE constraint, then IGNORE tells SQLite not to make a fuss about it and create an error.

It works reasonably well, but I would like to squeeze more performance out of it.

The strings are never removed from the database, nor are they altered, and so I don't need a general-purpose database, which makes me wonder if there is some single-purpose data store that would be faster for these specific tasks.

(There is an 8-year old question on this exact topic for which the accepted solution was to use SQLite and there are a few related questions but with slightly different requirements, such as the ability to remove / update strings.)

Comment: A hash based database like gdbm or Berkeley DB might be better.